# Add custom field in checkout and display it in WooCommerce admin order pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

In WooCommerce, I'm trying to add a custom field to checkout using [*"Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters"*](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/) official documentation. So I can see the field and it works well, but the problem is when I'm trying to see customer inputted information in the admin panel.

I'm using [simply show hooks](https://github.com/wp-plugins/simply-show-hooks) to see what hooks are fired and so on. And I can't see `woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address` firing. What I'm missing?! Here's my code in `functions.php` file:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_2']);
     unset($fields['shipping']['shipping_address_2']);
          $fields['billing']['shipping_time'] = array(
            'type' => 'select',
        'label'     => __('Laikas', 'woocommerce'),
    'placeholder'   => _x('Laikas', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'),
    'required'  => true,
    'class'     => array('form-row-wide'),
    'clear'     => true,
    'options' => array(
        'option_1' => 'nesvarbu',
        'option_2' => '8-12',
        'option_3' => '12-16',
        'option_4' => '16-20'
        )
     );


     return $fields;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );

function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
    global $post_id;
    $order = new WC_Order( $post_id );
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('Laikas').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta($order->get_id(), '_shipping_ftime', true ) . '</p>';
}
```

Comment: Why get the `$order` via the `$postid` when the `$order` is already passed as parameter to the function. Just use `$order->get_meta( '_shipping_time' );`

Comment: I was using your method then I tested this because it didn't work.

Comment: My answer therefore only contains part of the solution, it is to point you to a wrong approach

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    unset( $fields[ 'billing' ][ 'billing_address_2' ] );
    unset( $fields[ 'shipping' ][ 'shipping_address_2' ] );
    $fields[ 'billing' ][ 'shipping_time' ] = array(
        'type'           => 'select',
        'label'          => __( 'Laikas', 'woocommerce' ),
        'placeholder'    => _x( 'Laikas', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce' ),
        'required'       => true,
        'class'          => array( 'form-row-wide' ),
        'clear'          => true,
        'options'        => array(
            'option_1'   => 'nesvarbu',
            'option_2'   => '8-12',
            'option_3'   => '12-16',
            'option_4'   => '16-20'
        )
    );


    return $fields;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );

function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta( $order ) {
    global $post_id;
    $order = new WC_Order( $post_id );
    $options         = array(
            'option_1'   => 'nesvarbu',
            'option_2'   => '8-12',
            'option_3'   => '12-16',
            'option_4'   => '16-20'
        );
    echo '<p><strong>' . __( 'Laikas' ) . ':</strong> ' . $options[get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_shipping_time', true )] . '</p>';
}
```

Please try this snippet.

Comment: Hi, I tried your snipped and sadly still same result

Comment: @KarolisBeliašas - Please see the screenshot. That's what you are trying right?

Comment: Yes. Thats what I want.